# Query Index for Dictionary Based Queries

Tags: sql-server

What would be the most efficient way to query and index for the following:

```
SELECT * Persons.LastName A-D
SELECT * Persons.LastName E-L
SELECT * Persons.LastName M-R
SELECT * Persons.LastName S-Z
```

I'm using the following which is terribly inefficient and difficult to index:

```
WHERE LastName LIKE '[a-d]%'
```

Any ideas on a better way to go about this ?   I think this might be a good scenario for Filtered Index, however the where clause would need to be more sargable.

Thanks

Comment: A LIKE without a leading % IS sargable.  I'd look at your current indexing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Sam says, `LIKE '[a-d]%'` is SARGable (well almost). Almost because of a not optimized `Predicate` (see below for more info).

Example #1: if you run this query in [AdventureWorks2008R2](http://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com/releases/view/59211) database

```
SET STATISTICS IO ON;
SET NOCOUNT ON;

PRINT 'Example #1:';
SELECT  p.BusinessEntityID, p.LastName
FROM    Person.Person p
WHERE   p.LastName LIKE '[a-a]%'
```

then, you will get an execution plan based on `Index Seek` operator (optimized predicate: green rectangle, non-optimized predicate:red rectangle): 
[image]
The output for `SET STATISTICS IO` is

```
Example #1:
Table 'Person'. Scan count 1, logical reads 7
```

This means the server have to read 7 pages from buffer pool. Also, in this case, the index `IX_Person_LastName_FirstName_MiddleName` includes all columns required by `SELECT`, `FROM`and `WHERE` clauses: LastName and BusinessEntityID. If table has a clustered index then all non clustered indices will include the columns from clustered index key (BusinessEntityID is the key for PK_Person_BusinessEntityID clustered index).

But:

1) Your query have to show all columns because of `SELECT *` (it's a *bad* practice): BusinessEntityID, LastName, FirstName, MiddleName, PersonType, ..., ModifiedDate.

2) The index (`IX_Person_LastName_FirstName_MiddleName` in previous example) doesn't includes all required columns. This is the reason why, for this query, this index is a non-covering index.

Now, if you execute the next queries then you will get diff. [actual] execution plans (SSMS, Ctrl + M):

```
SET STATISTICS IO ON;
SET NOCOUNT ON;

PRINT 'Example #2:';
SELECT  p.*
FROM    Person.Person p
WHERE   p.LastName LIKE '[a-a]%';
PRINT @@ROWCOUNT;

PRINT 'Example #3:';
SELECT  p.*
FROM    Person.Person p
WHERE   p.LastName LIKE '[a-z]%';
PRINT @@ROWCOUNT;

PRINT 'Example #4:';
SELECT  p.*
FROM    Person.Person p WITH(FORCESEEK)
WHERE   p.LastName LIKE '[a-z]%';
PRINT @@ROWCOUNT;
```

Results:

```
Example #2:
Table 'Person'. Scan count 1, logical reads 2805, lob logical reads 0
911

Example #3:
Table 'Person'. Scan count 1, logical reads 3817, lob logical reads 0 
19972

Example #4:
Table 'Person'. Scan count 1, logical reads 61278, lob logical reads 0
19972
```

Execution plans:
[image]

Plus: the query will give you the number of pages for every index created on  'Person.Person':

```
SELECT i.name, i.type_desc,f.alloc_unit_type_desc, f.page_count, f.index_level FROM sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats(
    DB_ID(), OBJECT_ID('Person.Person'), 
    DEFAULT, DEFAULT, 'DETAILED' ) f 
INNER JOIN sys.indexes i ON f.object_id = i.object_id AND f.index_id = i.index_id
ORDER BY i.type


name                                    type_desc    alloc_unit_type_desc page_count index_level
--------------------------------------- ------------ -------------------- ---------- -----------
PK_Person_BusinessEntityID              CLUSTERED    IN_ROW_DATA          3808       0
PK_Person_BusinessEntityID              CLUSTERED    IN_ROW_DATA          7          1
PK_Person_BusinessEntityID              CLUSTERED    IN_ROW_DATA          1          2
PK_Person_BusinessEntityID              CLUSTERED    ROW_OVERFLOW_DATA    1          0
PK_Person_BusinessEntityID              CLUSTERED    LOB_DATA             1          0
IX_Person_LastName_FirstName_MiddleName NONCLUSTERED IN_ROW_DATA          103        0
IX_Person_LastName_FirstName_MiddleName NONCLUSTERED IN_ROW_DATA          1          1

...
```

Now, if you compare `Example #1` and `Example #2` (both returns 911 rows)

```
`SELECT p.BusinessEntityID, p.LastName ... p.LastName LIKE '[a-a]%'`
vs.
`SELECT * ... p.LastName LIKE '[a-a]%'`
```

then you will see two diff.:

a) 7 logical reads vs. 2805 logical reads and

b) `Index Seek` (#1) vs. `Index Seek` + `Key Lookup` (#2).

*You can see that the performance for `SELECT *` (#2) query is far worst (7 pages vs. 2805 pages).*

Now, if you compare `Example #3` and `Example #4` (both returns 19972 rows)

```
`SELECT * ... LIKE '[a-z]%`
vs.
`SELECT * ... WITH(FORCESEEK) LIKE '[a-z]%`
```

then you will see two diff.:

a) 3817 logical reads (#3) vs. 61278 logical reads (#4) and

b) `Clustered Index Scan` (PK_Person_BusinessEntityID has 3808 + 7 + 1 + 1 + 1 = 3818 pages) vs. `Index Seek` + `Key Lookup`.

*You can see that the performance for `Index Seek` + `Key Lookup` (#4)   query is far worst (3817 pages vs. 61278 pages).* In this case, you can see that and `Index Seek` on `IX_Person_LastName_FirstName_MiddleName` plus a `Key Lookup` on `PK_Person_BusinessEntityID` (clustered index) will give you a lower performance than a 'Clustered Index Scan'.

And all these bad execution plans are possible because of `SELECT *`.

Comment: I think you could have summed this whole answer up in a comment - "I hope you are not using SELECT * in your production code.  It can lead to performance problems."

Comment: @Sam: Easy to say, hard to believe ... without *(some)* arguments. And the internet is full of good and (most of them) bad/wrong comments.

Comment: It just seemed like you did a WHOLE lot of work for something that was not necessarily the problem ;)

Comment: @Sam: I did a whole lot of work because I like this subject. This matters for me.

Comment: @Sam: on topic > I would say that some comments have a *common* problem: forest versus trees.

Comment: @BogdanSahlean I got to give that to you just cause you went in.  To be honest my initial question (which I admit now I should have phrased better) was could this be made faster using filtered indexes.  Again thanks all for the feedback

Answer (score 1):

You predicate is sargable.

If you run this query on an indexed field:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    persons
WHERE   last_name >= 'a'
        AND last_name < 'e'
```

it produces the following plan:

```
  |--Nested Loops(Inner Join, OUTER REFERENCES:([MYDB].[dbo].[PERSONS].[ID]) OPTIMIZED)
       |--Index Seek(OBJECT:([MYDB].[dbo].[PERSONS].[IX_PERSONS_LAST_NAME]), SEEK:([MYDB].[dbo].[PERSONS].[LAST_NAME] >= 'a' AND [MYDB].[dbo].[PERSONS].[LAST_NAME] < 'E'),  WHERE:([MYDB].[dbo].[PERSONS].[LAST_NAME] like '[a-d]%') ORDERED FORWARD)
       |--Clustered Index Seek(OBJECT:([MYDB].[dbo].[PERSONS].[IX_PERSONS_LAST_NAME]), SEEK:([MYDB].[dbo].[PERSONS].[ID]=[MYDB].[dbo].[PERSONS].[ID]) LOOKUP ORDERED FORWARD)
```

which is equivalent to running this query:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    persons
WHERE   last_name >= 'a'
        AND last_name < 'e'
```

Comment: I get the same explain plan when running the LIKE or the <> operators.  Seems like SQL is doing pretty much the same thing behind the scenes, as it should.

Comment: So to clarify your answer, you might remove the alternative predicates that don't do anything to help.  Or do you think the <> executes faster?

Comment: @Sam: actually, the original predicate does behave exactly as it should so it might be worth keeping it

Answer (score 1):

I'd look at your explain plan and turn on STATISTICS IO and STATISTICS time to see if anything jumps out at you.