# Is my code hackable or secure enough?

Tags: sql-injection

I wonder if my app is injectable in the front end form, URL or in any other way.

Frontend:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
     <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLinkBack" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx">Go Back</asp:HyperLink> 
     <h3>
            Service Locations</h3>
     <table >
        <tr>             
            <td><asp:Label id="lblFilterValue" Text="Filter Value :" runat="server"></asp:Label></td>
            <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtFilterValue" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>           
            <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;</td>
            <td>
                 <asp:Label ID="FieldList" runat="server" Text="Filter By :"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td>
                 <asp:DropDownList ID="drpFields"  runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
            </td>            
         </tr>                       
    </table>
    <br />
            <asp:Button  ID="btnReset" runat="server"  Text="Reset" 
         onclick="btnReset_Click" /> 
            <asp:Button  ID="btnSearch" runat="server"  Text="Search" 
         onclick="btnSearch_Click" />  
</form>
```

Codebehind:

```
public static DataTable GetLocationFilter(string sFie6ld, string sValue)
    {



    DataTable dtdata = new DataTable();

    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LOCATIONS"].ConnectionString);
    SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("usp_SelectLocations", conn);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(comm);

    comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@sValue", sValue));

    da.Fill(dtdata);
    return dtdata;
    }
```

sp:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_SelectLocations]
@sValue varchar(250) 
AS
SELECT *
FROM  Locations
WHERE Title like @sValue + '%'
OR Division like @sValue + '%'
OR LocationType like @sValue + '%'
```

Comment: I'm thinking this is a programming question more than a security question. Perhaps it should be migrated to SO? (I'll let others determine this.)

Comment: As for your question- it doesn't appear to allow for SQL Injection. Obviously someone can type nasty SQL statements into the filter box, but I'm pretty sure they'll be encoded properly into the search string so you'll end up trying to match against the nasty SQL statement string (and get nothing back), rather than running the commands.

Comment: Unfortunately, we do not do code review here.

Comment: shucode, I applaud you for taking the time and effort to explore secure software development. Regardless of whether or not this post is closed, I encourage you not to give up on learning more. May I recommend visiting [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/)? Also, check out their [top 10](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Top_Ten_Project).

Comment: This would be better as a table valued function. Furthermore the `SELECT *` is not good for production code

Comment: @JamesAMohler While I understand this, could you please explain why `SELECT *` is not good for production code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18150139/production-perfomance-of-using-select-statements

Comment: And here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16088576/query-index-for-dictionary-based-queries/16092198#16092198

Comment: Thank you guys for your help. I will read up more on OWASP, try out Jame's suggestion table value functions and refrain from Selecting all. Finally TTT in short are you saying my sample is fine and cannot be hacked?